# react-i18next ignores options parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I wanted to organize better the language translation files of my project having to nest objects in the language file.

- Without nesting everything works fine
- Even nesting objects I can access them by passing the attribute directory in the t() function (ie: t('section.subsection.text')
- Documentation's solution doesn't work for me and I don't know why

I already tried printing the useTranslation instance to see if it was receiving the "keyPrefix" value but it always says 'undefined' either on the t or the fixedT function.

lang file is like this:

```
export const en = {
  section:{
    subsection:{
      text:'my text',
    }
  }
}
```

the file where I use the useTranslation hook:

```
const { t } = useTranslation('section', { keyPrefix: 'subsection' });

<h1>{t('text')}</h1>
```

this is taken from the documentation

```
// having resources like this:
/*{
  "translation": {
    "very": {
      "deeply": {
        "nested": {
          "key": "here"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}*/
// you can define a keyPrefix to be used for the resulting t function
const { t } = useTranslation('translation', { keyPrefix: 'very.deeply.nested' });
const text = t('key'); // "here"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an old node.js version.

Update it (nvm is a great tool for this) and voilà

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30596132)

Comment: @JuanMarco yes it does. I had that one problem and updating node.js version fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Node.js from 12.14.0 to 14.19.0 when I had this exact issue.